How to fix site images not showing on the custom domain
My site images are working well on localhost and on the default domain but on the custom domain, they do not show.
default domain - https://mrtrendy.payloadcms.app/
Custom domain - https://mrtrendydesigns.com/  &  https://www.mrtrendydesigns.com/
What am I not doing correctly?
I have followed all the steps listed in the documentation for adding a custom domain and
Accessing Files Outside of Payload Cloud
https://payloadcms.com/docs/cloud/projects#custom-domains

are you using s3 for storage or hosting images yourself?

Have you tried settings allowed remote patterns for your image source?

To protect your application from malicious users, configuration is
required in order to use external images. This ensures that only
external images from your account can be served from the Next.js Image
Optimization API. These external images can be configured with the
remotePatterns property in your next.config.js file, as shown below:
next.config.js
module.exports = {   images: {
remotePatterns: [
{
protocol: 'https',
hostname: 'example.com',
port: '',
pathname: '/account123/**',
},
],   }, }

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#remotepatterns

This is what I have in my next config
images: {     domains: ['localhost', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL]       .filter(Boolean)       .map(url => url.replace(/https?:\/\//, '')),   },
I added my other domains and nothing changed.
